# Run a VBA script with a SQL Query written in the Personal Workbook, from a different workbook and using the data from that workbook

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I wrote a query in VBA that runs fine when running locally in the Workbook where it was written. I ran into some issues once I try to write it in the the personal workbook as to always have access to the Macro. In the From [sheet$] statement, it looks for it in the personal workbook which of course is missing.

What is the correct way as to have the macro written in the personal workbook, and to reference the Active.Workbook.Worksheet within the SQL From statement.

Here is the code, thank you in advance.

```
Option Explicit
Sub GeneralJourney_Mapping()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long


Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("GeneralJournal")
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"

Dim qSelectInvDetails As String
qSelectInvDetails = "Select [Company Code (4)], sum(Credit)-sum(Debit) as Credit" & _
                    " From [ws.Name$] " & _
                    " Group By [Company Code (4)]"

rs.Open qSelectInvDetails, conn

ws.Range("B17:K" & lastRow & "").ClearContents
ws.Range("B17").CopyFromRecordset rs


rs.Close
conn.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing

End Sub`
```

I have tried to write the address and was expecting the SQL From statement to search within the Active.Workbook.Worksheets.

Comment: Presumably `ws.Name$` is `GeneralJournal$`. Also try changing `ThisWorkbook.FullName` to `ActiveWorkbook.FullName`

Comment: `" From [ws.Name$] " & _` >> `" From [" & ws.Name & "$] " & _`